# RegExp добавить букву в конец строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Получаю значение, состоящее только из цифр, из переменной и мне надо добавить в конец букву `p`. Вот, что пытался, но попусту

> elem.val(num2.replace(/\d+$, ' p' /));

Надо сделать именно через регулярные выражения, т.к. число приходит по клику на цифру и обновляется сразу же, если сделать просто  `+ ' p'`, то выйдет `1 р2 р3 р4 р`, а надо `1234 р`

Полный код

```
  $('.btn').on('keyup', function (e) {
        // skip for arrow keys
  if (event.which >= 37 && e.which <= 40) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  var $this = $(this);
  var num = $this.val().replace(/ /gi, "").split("").reverse().join("");

  var num2 = RemoveRougeChar(num.replace(/(.{3})/g, "$1 ").split("").reverse().join(""));

  // the following line has been simplified. Revision history contains original.

  //здесь значение записывается, этот кусок кода в вопросе 
  $this.val(a.replace(num2.replace(/$/, '$& p'));


  function RemoveRougeChar(convertString) {

    if (convertString.substring(0, 1) == ",") {
      return convertString.substring(1, convertString.length);
    }

    return convertString;
  }
});
```

Comment: `num2.replace(/\d+$/, '$& p')`

Comment: `num2.replace(/\d+($)/, '$0 p')`

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, попробуй свой вариант :-)

Comment: @Grundy работает, я тоже такой делал. Тут загвоздка в том, по нажатию на цифру в val добавляется цифра и сразу же "p", при следующем нажатии берется предыдущее val + цифра + снова "p". Плохо описал я..

Comment: вот и выходит 1 p2 p..

Comment: `num2.replace(/[^\d]/g, '') + ' р'`?

Comment: @Yaant тогда пробелы убираются

Comment: может вам сохранить текущее число в переменную (без p) и после вытереть значение. После чего  выполните предложенную предыдущую "функцию" только добавьте еще запомненное число.

Answer (score 1):

Как оказалось, ответ примитивный и лежал на поверхности...

```
var cutAllText = num2.replace('p', '')
var addText = cutAllText.replace(/$/, 'p')

$this.val(addText);
```

Comment: тогда ты вообще без регулярок мог обойтись: проверить если последний символ -не р - тогда добавить его к строке